# Error 800 while connecting to VPN

Tags: windows-xp, vpn

I am trying to connect to my office network through VPN. It used to work fine earlier but now as soon as I hit connect, I get Error 800:

> Error 800: Unable to establish VPN Connection. The VPN server may be unreachable, or security parameters may not be configured properly for this connection.

I am using Windows XP and I am able to ping the VPN server successfully. I have Symantec Endpoint Protection installed (if it matters). I have tried disabling it as well but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

COULD be a GRE routing issue on your home router (mine had the crap at one time).

PPTP VPN use a TCP cahnnel for cordination, and then the packets are sent using GRE (ip subprotocol 47 - not tcp, not udp). If the router or a firewall drops those....